# PostgreSQL select query on table that is being updated

Tags: postgresql, concurrency

I assume this question has been asked before, but unfortunately I cannot find the answer to my question.

I have a table, and I am using an `update` statement to update a column. Simultaneously I am running a `create table` query with a `select` statement that is retrieving data from the table and column that is also being updated.

My questions are: can this lead to wrong results in the output of the `create table` statement? does the `update` query finish 1st then the `create table` with the `select` execute? I just know that the `create table` statement is taking way longer to execute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PostgreSQL readers never lock writers and vice versa. This is guaranteed by PostgreSQL's MVCC implementation that keeps old row versions around.

If the updating transaction isn't finished yet, the reading transaction will see the old value, and the result is consistent.

There is nothing inside PostgreSQL that should slow down the `SELECT` statement noticeably, but of course I/O contention is a possible explanation.